# what are the differences between an normal bootstrap text field styles and a mat-text field styles

Tags: angular, angular-material2

What are the differences between the styles of a normal text field and a mat-text field, i.e.:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

AND

```html
<input matInput class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

Comment: And why are you asking this exactly? Why don't you try comparing them yourself? I'm marking this as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I am asking this because when I tried I couldn't figure out any differences. Also I couldn't find the styles defined for a mat input field.

Comment: This is not opinion based. I hope this question will be helpful for people who are new to angular materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your input in a `mat-form-field` container to see the difference.

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="value">
</mat-form-field>
```